# Process exited normally bibtex error

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I have a bibtext file:

```
@book{a1,
    author    = "Shasha, D. and Zhu, Y.",
    title     = "High Performance Discovery in Time series, Techniques and Case Studies",
    publisher = "Springer",
    year      = "2004"
 }
,
@book {a2,
 author    = "Chatfield, C.",
    title     = "The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction",
    publisher = "Chapman\&Hall",
    year      = "2003",
    edition="sixth"   
}
,
@inbook {a3,
author="Shasha, D. and Zhu, Y.",
title     = "High Performance Discovery in Time series, Techniques and Case Studies",
 publisher = "Springer",
    year      = "2004",
    CHAPTER="Data reduction and Transformation Thechniques",
   PAGES=9-10
}
,
@inbook {a5,
author    = "Chatfield, C.",
    title     = "The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction",
    publisher = "Chapman\&Hall",
    year      = "2003",
    edition="sixth",
    CHAPTER="Simple Descriptive Techniques",
   PAGES=22-28
}
```

I get this error:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9) The top-level auxiliary file: test2.aux The style file: ieeetr.bst Database file #1: refh.bib I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 22 of file refh.bib : pages=9 : -10 I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 32 of file refh.bib : pages=22 : -28 I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry You're missing a field name---line 36 of file refh.bib : : %author = {millercommamatt}, (Error may have been on previous line) I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "test" (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited normally
```

what should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: I think the pages should be separated by double hyphens: `--`. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX#Bibliographic_information_file

Comment: wrap the `pages` data in either braces or double quotes.  only a single page number (not a span) will get past the checker otherwise.

Comment: @darthbith Double hyphens should be used for grammatical reasons (see, e.g., [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2126)), but this would not cause this error.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you want to add an answer?

Answer (score 2):

wrap the pages data in either braces or double quotes.

only a single page number, not a span, will get past the checker otherwise.

Comment: Also the commas between the entries are redundant; not a problem with BibTeX that ignores them, but other software might not. A stylistic remark is that it should be `Chapman \& Hall`, with spaces.